# What are the Working versions of Jars required in the Compilation of a report made with iReport 4.1.3

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports, ireport

i made a couple of Reports using iReport 4.1.3 and i want to compile them through a java application.

but i don't know exactly the version of the jars that works with iReport 4.1.3.

i'm using the following jars :

```
 commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0

 commons-collections-3.1

 commons-digester-2.0

 commons-logging-1.1.1

 groovy-all-1.0-jsr-02

 itext-1.1.4

 jasperreports- 3.1.4
```

and i get this Error while creating the reports from the Java Application :

```
 Exception in thread "main"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V
```

so, can you please help, by Providing versions, or links.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You can see all dependencies in jasperreports's pom.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use iText 2.1.5, in which com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V 
is available.

Answer (score 1):

As per your error, certainly problem is with your iText jar. Try out with the latest version of iText.

Comment: Yes, i used iText-2.1.5 and now it's Working.